# XTC Website with new second Domain

Tags: php, html

The problem is I have gotten a Website and a domain (the webshop already has a domain the one I get should be a second one) witch need to connect to that website, but not as a redirection (don't ask why I don't know either why he want it that way).

Both Domains are by the same host and for some reason the second domain I should configure doesn't want to work.

I only get :

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /shop/inc/xtc_db_connect.inc.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /shop/includes/application_top.php(196): xtc_db_connect() #1 /shop/index.php(25): include('/kunden/193457_...') #2 {main} thrown in /shop/inc/xtc_db_connect.inc.php on line 24`

The normal domain works perfectly, but the one I need to configure only gets errors.

I already looked into that file and in this `xtc_db_connect.inc.php` on line 24 is this :

`$$link = mysqli_connect ($server, $username, $password);`

I already searched and tried, but everything I do doesn't work.

Anyone a suggestion? What I can be?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with any domain configuration, unless it's pointing to a different site (or if the host has some special setup we know nothing about). Without any more information, it's pretty hard to come up with possible reasons/solutions to this issue.

Comment: Btw, is `$$link` a typo when you pasted the code or is it in the original code?

Comment: What for informations do you need?

Comment: It's the orginal code

Comment: That looks odd. That creates a variable named by the contents of the `$link`-variable.Ex. `$link = 'foo'; $$link = ...` would create a variable called `$foo`. Demo: https://3v4l.org/21RS0. What we need to know, basically the setup. VPS? Shared hosting? OS? Are the domains pointing to the same document root? Is there some setting in the setup that set different environments for different domains? Ex: the `mysql_*`-extension is removed in PHP7. Have you talked to the hosting company?

Comment: The ´$$link = ...´ part looks really odd but its not the only one in the code - Shared hosting - OS I don't really know. - Both Domains are pointing to the same document. - Is there some setting in the setup that set different environments for different domains? I don' know what you mean - It's an old Webshop so I don't think that it works on PHP7 - And no I didn't call the hosting company

Comment: I would recommend you to contact the hosting company. We don't know what their setup looks like so it's pretty impossible for us to know what's going on.